# Is there any other possibility to convert String to double?

Tags: java

I'm learning a Java and I have a problem in one of my project called "point of sale". When the program reads a barcode from the user, it starts to search for the proper product in products.txt. When it finds the product, next it should set the values to the created object. The problem occurs when I try to convert String to double. I spend almost 2 hours to solve it and I didn't succeed. I need your help.

So I have tried:

```
double dbl = Double.valueOf(parts[2]);
p.set_price(dbl);
```

```
double dbl = Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
p.set_price(dbl);
```

```
double dbl = new Double(parts[2]);
p.set_price(dbl);
```

And also tried a combinations like this (but it doesn't work):

```
p.set_price(Double.valueOf(parts[2].ToString()));
```

There is only a method

```
public void newSale() { 
    Products p = new Products();

    // Barcode
    System.out.print("Barcode:");
    p.set_barcode(scan.next());

    // Find the product
    try{
    File file = new File("products.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String x = scan.next();
        if(x.contains(p.get_barcode())) {
            String[] parts = x.split(";");
            p.set_barcode(parts[0]);
            p.set_name(parts[1]);
            try{
                double dbl = Double.valueOf(parts[2]);
                p.set_price(dbl);
            }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }

        }               
    }            
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.print(p.get_name()+"\t"+p.get_price());
}
```

It will be good if anyone will help me to understand why conversion and assigning don't work.

Comment: Please define "not working". What error do you get?

Comment: In your file first line is `Barcode;Name;Price` so value at index `2` is `Price` which you cannot convert into double and also next line is `0101;Pomarańcze;4,36` where value at index `2` is `4,36` either you cannot convert it to

Comment: Why do you think you need *another* solution?

Comment: Yes, you want the `DecimalFormat` class.  It can be made to interpret your commas as decimal separators.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The problem was in the txt file, I should use dots instead of commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the double data type, the integer part is separated from the fractional part by a dot. In the file products.txt, replace commas with dots in the prices. That should help :)